# Compare each element of the array to state with react

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Hi i dont't know how to compare each elements of the array to the state:

[image]

```
doesCustomerExist = () => {
  const { customers } = this.props;
  let result = customers.map(c => c.phone)
  if(result === this.state.phone)
    return (console.log('already exist'))
    console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: is ```this.state.phone``` an `array` or a single element (`string`)?

Comment: Please edit the question with more information.  Which var is the array you wanna compare?  Put in comments the value of the state and the log of 'result'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if an array contains a given element.

For instance:

```js
const phone = "123";
const customers = ["111", "222", "333", "123"];

const isInArray = customers.indexOf(phone) > -1;

console.log(isInArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this simply use [Array.inlcudes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const phone = "123";
const customers = ["111", "222", "333", "123"];

const isFound = customers.includes(phone)

console.log(isFound);
```